# Correct and efficient way to do mass http posts with netty

Tags: java, performance, http, out-of-memory, netty

I need to perform mass http posts with netty 4.1 where the http body is static (=always the same) across all messages.

I came up with this (simplified) solution but i am not sure if is the most efficient and performant way to do it. The question is especially focused on the ByteBuf handling and OOM prevention.

```
    final String requestBody = "... huge static post content ...";

    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).handler(new HttpClientInitializer());

        b.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);

        int requestCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        latch = new CountDownLatch(requestCount);
        ByteBuf requestBodyBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(requestBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).asReadOnly();
        DefaultFullHttpRequest postRequest = postRequest(requestBodyBuf);

        Channel ch = b.connect("localhost", 8080).sync().channel();

        //write a lot (and as fast as possible) post messages which are are all equal
        //is .retainedDuplicate() correct and ressource efficient?
        for(int i=0; i<requestCount; i++) {
            ch.writeAndFlush(postRequest.retainedDuplicate());
        }

        latch.await();
        ch.close();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
```

Full code is here:
https://gist.github.com/salyh/3360af420a4ce2f9af5d9accc48c89b1

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to:

```
    for(int i=0; i<requestCount; i++) {
        ch.write(postRequest.retainedDuplicate());
    }
    // This will ensure you can do a gathering write (writev).
    ch.flush();

    // As you retain on each write you should release the last reference after done.
    postRequest.release();
```

This will allow you to just do one syscall (when flush() is called).